# How to extract the value of an object inside an incomplete JSON array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have a node app from which I get some data. I have gone through other questions asked on SO..but Im unable to figure this out. I need to access the value of *result* . The code below shows the exact response I get from server.  None of the methods described in other answers like JSON.parse() etc seem to work.

```
    [{
      query: {
                "parameter1": "12",
                "parameter2": "13",
                "parameter3": 25
               }
      result: 6.58443
    }]
```

EDIT : As mentioned in the comments below, unfortunately I cant fix this on the server side(Comes from an external source). I have to deal with this broken JSON on my end and extract the value of result.
EDIT 2 : Yes, there are multiple arrays like this. The content and comma part doesnt change. They are listed one after the other.

Comment: That json is invalid because `key-value` pairs must be separated by `,` comma.

Comment: @brk dealing with invalid JSON strings is hardly what I'd call trivial...

Comment: You will either have to fix the server to return valid JSON or.... it gets real ugly real fast.

Comment: @brk. The problem is the type of response Im getting from the server. Its not a proper JSON object which I can parse. I have no control over the response from the server..so I need to handle the parsing on my end.

Comment: Because of the lack of a comma between key-value pairs, this is not JSON. You could semi-trivially write a parser for this, but it may not be the correct solution. Do you have the ability to fix the bug on the server side?

Comment: @JoelCornett Unfortunately I dont. :(  I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: You can parse this, and there are ways of parsing invalid JSON. eg. https://github.com/RyanMarcus/dirty-json  But a trivial way might be just to use a simple regex to extract the value.

Comment: This could be as trivial as `responseStr.replace("}", "},")` but probably not: are there ever more objects in the array? more entries in the object? are parameters and results always strings/numbers, or sometimes other types? We can't write a surefire fix for this without knowing a lot more about what else the string *could* be.

Comment: I recommend using a superset of JSON that accepts trailing commas and do a string replacement of “}” with “},”. It’s not pretty, and it will only work on a limited class of objects (objects without string literals containing “}”).

Comment: @apsillers I have updated my answer. Yes, there are multiple such objects like this..but the format remains same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact you can't receive that data though any library function that expects JSON like jQuery $.ajax() with `dataType='json'` option (you should use `dataType="text"` in this case to avoid premature error being triggered I mean).

...you obviously need to fix JSON syntax before parsing it (as I understood you already know).

If it is what you are asking for, your best bet is a regular expression search and replace.

If you know you won't get things such as '{bracket: "}"}' it is pretty simple:

**Example:**

```
var wrong = `
    [{
      "query": {
                "parameter1": "12",
                "parameter2": "13",
                "parameter3": 25
               }
      "result": 6.58443
    }]
`;

var good = wrong.replace(/}(?!\s*[,}\]])/g, '},');

var json = JSON.parse(good);

console.log(json);
```

This is the simplest example that fixes the input you provided.

Even though it does not fix the same problem after an end of array (']') and, most importantly, if it were fixed it (or simply the string ended with '}' instead of ']' it would added an extra ',' at the end messing up things again.

A more polite approach solving beferementioned issues is to replace the `var good = ...` row in previous code with this one:

```
var good = wrong.replace(/(}|])(?!\s*[,}\]])/g, '$1,')
    .replace(/,\s*$/, '')
;
```

Now, you have a valid *json* object so accessing any property in it is pretty obvious. For example, `json[0].result` is what you asked for.

On the other hand, if you can have brackets inside literal strings, it will be much more difficult (even not impossible). But I figure out it would hardly be the case...

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to encapsulate your result with back-ticks to have a (valid) string literal, then get result with any method you want, for example a matching regex :

```js
var arr =  `[{
      "query": {
                "parameter1": "12",
                "parameter2": "13",
                "parameter3": 25
               }
      "result": 6.58443
}]`;

var match = arr.match(/("result": )(\d*.\d*)/);

console.log(match[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions provided above..all point to a hacky way of solving this. The only way to solve this issue was with the help of good old Regex expressions. To my surprise..even though there are lots of libraries to handle JSON parsing etc, to solve edge cases(Common when dealing with small clients or unreliable data source), there is no library which can handle this scenario. 
@Bitifet's answer is what solves this problem..with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Purely for illustrative purposes, the below code "rewrites" JSON that is missing commas into JSON that has commas in the appropriate places. The advantage of using this over a `replace` or a regular expression is that this code guarantees that string literals are handled correctly:

```
const LEX_EXPR = (
  '('
    + '"(?:\\\\(?:["\\\\/bfnrt]|u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})|[^"])*"|'
    + '-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\\d+)?|'
    + '(?:true|false|null)'
  + ')|'
  + '([{\\[])|'
  + '([}\\]])|'
  + '([:,])|'
  + '(\\s+)|'
  + '(.)'
)

function lex(string) {
  let tokens = []
  let expr = new RegExp(LEX_EXPR, 'mguy')
  let match = expr.exec(string)
  while(match !== null) {
    let [
      value,
      atom,
      begin, end, sep,
      whitespace,
      junk
    ] = match
    let type
    if (atom != null) {
      type = "atom"
    } else if (begin != null) {
      type = "begin"
    } else if (end != null) {
      type = "end"
    } else if (sep != null) {
      type = "sep"
    } else if (whitespace != null) {
      type = "whitespace"
    } else {
      // junk. ignore or raise exception
      throw `Invalid character: ${junk}`
    }
    tokens.push({ type, value })
    match = expr.exec(string)
  }
  return tokens
}

function shouldInsertComma(prev, cur) {
  if (!prev || !cur) {
    return false
  }
  if (prev.type == "begin" || prev.type == "sep") {
    return false
  }
  return cur.type == "begin" || cur.type == "atom"
}

function rewrite(tokens) {
  let out = []
  let prevNonWhitespace = null
  for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    let cur = tokens[i]
    if (cur.type !== "whitespace") {
      if (shouldInsertComma(prevNonWhitespace, cur)) {
        out.push({ type: "sep", value: "," })
      }
      prevNonWhitespace = cur
    }
    out.push(cur)
  }
  return out
}

function joinTokens(tokens) {
  return tokens.map(({ value }) => value).join('')
}

const invalid = `
{
  "foo": {
    "bat": "bing}"
    "boo": "bug"
  }
  "result": "yes"
}
`
const rewritten = joinTokens(rewrite(lex(invalid)))
console.log(JSON.parse(rewritten))  // { foo: { bat: 'bing}', boo: 'bug' }, result: 'yes' }
```